# Injecting libraries/dependencies into AWS Lambda with Serverless Framework

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

really quick question; do I need to install from the command prompt  `sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements` into each serverless framework project that I make to load python dependencies into the stack/lambda function I am going to deploy?

I had been playing with Serverless Framework in trying to use it for a project involving AWS Lambda and python for csv transformations. As such I'd like to use pandas and numpy within the Lambda function.

I have Docker installed and in the yaml file have

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

But was wondering if I need to repeatedly install that  `sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements` each time I create a new project. I noticed that if I do that it downloads two json documents package-lock.json and package.json into the project folder. But I had noticed though that other tutorials did not have those json files despite using dependencies, so I wasn't quite sure if this is a repeated step I do per project.

Answer (score 2):

Great question!

The Serverless Framework is a [project](http://github.com/serverless/serverless) written in NodeJS.

Specifically `sls plugin install` basically just runs `npm install` under the [hood](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#install). This means that `sls plugin install` just fetches the plugin from NPM and installs it (via adding it to the project `package.json` and `package-lock.json`)

I'd *guess* you can likely run `npm i -g serverless-python-requirements` to install the library globally for your system, and then I suspect you could just declare the plugin in the `plugins` block of each project's `serverless.yml` file, and be done.

Comment: however doing a `npm i -g serverless-python-requirements` into each project folder (individually per project) is neither necessary nor typically done? If that's the case, I don't know why I thought that, but it's lead me down an odd rabbit hole.

Comment: `-g` installs a package _globally_, which means you won't need to install it anywhere else.

Comment: Ok, interesting. Yeah, I've been declairing the pluggins in the plugin block of each yaml file (like shown in the original post) for each project and then ALSO running `sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements` into each project, but then wondered if that was over-kill.